# What design pattern(s) should i use for a price calculation?

Tags: design-patterns, decorator, calculation, composite, price

I'm refactoring the price calculation of a car and tried to use the decorator pattern. This worked well for the price of the car, but to this price I should add (with ajax) other prices for the extra equipments, which each should be calculated also using his own pattern decorator.

So the question is: does the decorator pattern still fits in this context? Should i use another pattern? How do i combine these objects with each other?

I must specify that the code is difficult to understand (spaghetti code), with many IFs and HTML mixed. Any advice will be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you can't/won't modify the original classes/beans (the car, the equipment...), since you adopted the Decorator.

Try this. Make all decorators implementing a common interface, declaring an `accept(Visitor v)` method and the `getPrice()` method.

I would then use the Visitor pattern to do the magic, so you can put all the logic into the Visitor implementation: this would require only a small modification to items that you want to sum up (an `accept(Visitor v)` method), and you can put this into the Decorator.

To add another operation you simply create another Visitor implementation.

Obviously you can simply use a loop on all the items summing up the result of the getPrice method.

Another approach could be: don't decorate the items, and keep their price in a Map.